# Using AJAX to pass variable into PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked around various other questions relating to this topic but I am still struggling to find a solution to my query.

In my system I am allowing the admin to append extra form nodes to the file so they may input any extra required data, this data is then submitted to the DB to generate pages in the main portion of the site.

I am new to the concept of passing the data back via AJAX so I may be misunderstanding something but here is my code.

Add Node Control

```
<div id="nodeControl">
    <div id="addNode">
        <a id="nodeLink" href="#">+</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slideOut">Click to add a new section</div>
```

Add Node click response function

```
var nodeCount = 2;
        $("#nodeLink").click(function(){
            // Local Variables
            var newSection = '<br/><div id="sectionInfo"><div id="sectionWrap"><div id="sectionInner"><label class="inst head">Section ' + nodeCount + '</label><input class="textOver" type="text" name="sectionTitle' + nodeCount + '" value="<?php $title; ?>"> <label class="inst ib">Please enter any text you would like associated with the section.</label> <textarea style="margin-top: 3px" name="sectionContent' + nodeCount + '" value="<?php $body; ?>"></textarea> <label class="inst ib">Please upload the image associated with this section, .PNG reccomended.</label> <input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" name="img' + nodeCount + '" id="upload" /> <input type="button" id="fileStyle" class="fSOver" value="Upload Pump Image!" /> </div> </div> </div>' ;

            // Append the new section to the document and increment the node count
            $('#sections').append(newSection);
            nodeCount += 1;


            // Call AJAX to pass to PHP
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "../section.php",
                data: { setSection : newSection },
                success: function() {
                    alert("Success, ajax parsed");
                }
            });

            $(".successDiv").slideDown(150);
            $(".successDiv").delay(1500).slideUp(150);

            return false;
        });
```

Node count is instantiated to "2" here, when a node is added the number is appended to the name attribute of any input elements on my form i.e. header2, header3 etc.
This is so when my form is eventually submitted I can loop through each data field and submit it to the database.

As I currently understand the AJAX data variable uses key pairs `{ a : b }` where `a = return key` and `b = return value`, I want PHP to be able to access that returned value and store it into an array which can be looped through at the end.
Currently the success message is triggered on my AJAX call but I am unable to access the values in PHP, instead I am thrown an "Undefined index of sections defined".

```
$section = array();
$setSection = $_POST['setSection'];
$section[] = $setSection;
```

Comment: Thanks Blaze I will look into some temp storage mechanisms, I guess if I stored it in a DB I wouldn't have to explicitly pass the return data to php

Comment: By the way, I hope your JavaScript isn't running until after the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP won't store every `setSection` variable you pass it over time; each time your script is called, its variables are reset. You probably want to store the variable in a database or session variable.

Here's one approach, using [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

```
session_start(); // unless you already started one
if (!isset($_SESSION['section'])) {
    $_SESSION['section'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['section'], $_POST['setSection']);
```

Comment: I shall try that, I am already using an 'admin' session to handle the user being logged in, I'm guessing I can use that session to handle the above function? But just change !isset to isset

Comment: I have that implemented and understand how that works, however PHP is still complaining that "setSection" is an undefined index

Comment: So, that variable isn't getting POSTed to your script like you thought?

Comment: Nope, I guess its not getting passed back to my script, but the success function is triggering so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you change your success callback to: `function(data) { alert("Success: "+data); }`, you can display output from the PHP script to debug your code further.

Comment: Appreciate your help Blaze, I am going to probably restructure a lot of my markup I think I can see the root of my problem now.

Thanks again.

Comment: After taking your advice, I restructured my document and have gotten this working!